# Xamarin.form Scrollview is not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using visual studio 2017, I created a shared project with portable class library, I added the following code in to MainPage.xaml.cs class file,

```
var scroll = new ScrollView();
Content = scroll;
var stack = new StackLayout();

stack.Children.Add(new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Red,   HeightRequest = 600, WidthRequest = 600 });

stack.Children.Add(new Entry());

content=stack ;
```

then I deployed the project, and run it in local machine, I found that the scrolling is not working.
what am I missing in here?
Any help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding the `stack` to the scroll. Edit it like this:

```
var scroll = new ScrollView();
var stack = new StackLayout();

stack.Children.Add(new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Red,   HeightRequest = 600, WidthRequest = 600 });

stack.Children.Add(new Entry());

// Note how I add the stack object to the ScrollView here
scroll.Content = stack;

// And add the ScrollView to the Content of the page instead of the stack
Content = scroll;
```

Comment: Can you do this using XAML as well? I tried to do this using XAML. But it's not working.

Comment: Sure, everything in code is possible with XAML and vice versa.

Comment: My XAML is like this. <ScrollView> <StackLayout> ........ </StackLayout></ScrollView>. But it's not scrolling on Android. Could you please tell me if I'm missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

var stack = new StackLayout();

stack.Children.Add(new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Red,   HeightRequest = 600, WidthRequest = 600 });

stack.Children.Add(new Entry());

Content = new ScrollView { Content = stack }